# How does Django handle importing of apps?

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

I would like to know how Django's imports work. For example, in this code:

```
# in some_app/views.py

from another_app.models import UserModel
# another_app is another app of the same project
```

there's an import statement that imports `UserModel` from `models.py` in `another_app` (another app of the same project).

I was just wondering how Django handles this importing because usual Django project's directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── another_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── some_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── some_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

`some_app` and `another_app` are separate directories.

I want to know how the importing works because I want to find a workaround for one of my projects that have separate directories but requires each other's functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you register  the app name in installed app in django settings you can easily handle most migrations and other stuff other wise you can just branch off from the folder of the app name.
What i recommend is making a separate directory named app and you can place all your app inside app director so the app and project directory gets separated easily and your import will also be easy

you can import in this manner after wards

```
from app.some_new_app_name.models import MyModel
from app.some_new_app_name_2.models import MyModel2
```